# How to create SwapView dynamically using Dojo

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Dojo v1.8 with Worklight; I would like create a SwapView dynamically in View, but I'm encountering problems...

**HTML code:**

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="listeInscriptionView"
            data-dojo-props="selected:false,scrollDir:'vh'"
            style="background-image: url('images/bg-texture.jpg');" 
                            data-dojo-id="id">
    </div>
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
var view = registry.byId(listeInscriptionView);
    alert(view);

    for(var i = 1; i < 3; i++ ){
        var swap = new dojox.mobile.SwapView({
            id: i, 
            selected:false 
        });

        var head = new dojox.mobile.Heading({
            label:'Swap' + i,
        });
        swap.addChield(head);
        view.addChield(swap);
        alert("test" + i);
    }
```

The above does not work. How I can create the widget SwapView dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that a copy of your actual code? I have not actually tested it but there are syntax errors and typos:

```
registry.byId(listeInscriptionView);
```

should be

```
registry.byId("listeInscriptionView");
```

(missing quotes), and

```
swap.addChield(head);
view.addChield(swap);
```

should be

```
swap.addChild(head);
view.addChild(swap);
```

Maybe it works better with these errors fixed?